# Remove an ActionListener from JButton

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, actionlistener

I want to remove the action listener from a `JButton`. But I have an `ActionListener` like this:

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          btn.removeActionListener();
     }
});
```

But the `btn.removeActionListener();` needs parameters inside the parenthesis so I'm a little stumped.

Comment: `btn.removeActionListener(this);` in order to remove it inside an action listener.

Comment: that didn't work

Comment: *"I want to remove the action listener from a `JButton`"* .. Why? Subject to the answer to that question (and yes, I expect to see an answer) it might be better to create an `Action` for the button. An `Action` can be disabled, and in doing so will indicate to the user that the button is not usable.

Comment: Lets say the button is on the main menu, but every time I call that main menu it adds yet another action listener. Although I just solved it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the ActionListener.

If you read the [AbstractButton API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html), the JButton has a `public ActionListener[] getActionListeners()`, which gives you an array of listeners. Get them (there is probably only one), and then remove it (or them if more than one -- using a for-loop) from the button.

For example

```
ActionListener[] listeners = btn.getActionListeners();
for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
    btn.removeActionListener(listener);
}
```

Having said that, I'm wondering if this might be [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where a better solution is by going with a different approach. Perhaps you just need to put a boolean statement within the listener, and vary its behavior (the code that it calls) depending on the state of a flag (boolean field) within the class.

Comment: I'm a little confused. i'm sorry I'm new to coding. Is this for loop just another way to make an actionlistener? By that I mean, when i click the button, whatever is in the foorloop with activate? Because it's not working.

Comment: @L0raxeoC: ??? no, it has nothing to do with creating another ActionListener. Your comment confuses me as the for loop does exactly as you requested -- removes all action listeners for a given button.